# while writing selenium scripting in website and but it will not go sidebar options window through selenium scripts

Tags: selenium

While   writing  selenium   scripts  in a web page  and  it's  working   auto login window, but  while  going  sidebar options  in website is not  working

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mCSB_22_container']/ul/li[8]/i"));
```

I have  used  these  xpath   but  not  working

```
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" routerlinkactive="active" title="Alert Configuration" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:rgb(214, 111, 111);"></i>
  </li>
  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" title="Device Profile">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cog" style="color:lightBlue;"></i>
  </li>

  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" title="Poles">
    <img _ngcontent-c11="" src="./assets/images/lamp-pole-group-12x12.png"> </li>
  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" title="Lamps">
    <img _ngcontent-c11="" src="./assets/images/pole-lamps-12x12.png" class="mCS_img_loaded"> </li>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" routerlinkactive="active" title="Commissioning Process" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">

    <img _ngcontent-c11="" src="./assets/images/Commissioning-Process.png" class="mCS_img_loaded">
  </li>
  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" title="Groups" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-users" style="color:#8edd34;"></i>
  </li>

  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" title="Reports" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="color:#d3d347;"></i>
  </li>
  <!---->

  <li _ngcontent-c11="" routerlinkactive="active" title="Archival" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-archive"></i>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Dashboard
      
        
          
        Device Trends
      
        
          
        Alerts – Notifications

```
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="li-h" style="display: inherit;">User
    Management</li>
  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" routerlinkactive="active" title="Users" tabindex="0" class="active">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#3289c8;">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-user mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Users</li>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Roles &amp; Permissions" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:lightBlue;">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-check-square-o mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Roles &amp; Permissions</li>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="User Activity Tracking" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>User Activity Tracking</li>

  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="li-h" style="display: inherit;">Configuration
    Settings</li>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Project Configuration" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:lightBlue;">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-handshake-o mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Project Configuration</li>

    <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class=" overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="One Step Onboarding" tabindex="0">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff;">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-user mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>One Step Onboarding</li>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="arrow-toggle collapsed" data-target="#collapseHierarchy" data-toggle="collapse" title="Hierarchy" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-bar-chart mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Hierarchy
    <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fr mlr10">
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-plus caret1 plr5"></span>
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-minus caret1 plr5"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="collapse " id="collapseHierarchy">
    <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Hierarchy Definition" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">Hierarchy Definition</li>
    <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Hierarchy Creation" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">Hierarchy Creation</li>
  </ul>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class=" overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Alert Configuration" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:rgb(214, 111, 111);">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Alert Configuration</li>
  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="arrow-toggle collapsed" data-target="#collapseExample" data-toggle="collapse" title="Device Profiles">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:lightblue">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-cog mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Device Profile
    <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fr mlr10 ">
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-minus caret1 plr5"></span>
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-plus caret1 plr5"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <!----><ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Device Profile Master" tabindex="0">Device Profile Master</li>
    <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Profile Settings" tabindex="0">Profile
      Settings</li>
  </ul>

  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="li-h">Device
    Onboarding</li>

  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="arrow-toggle collapsed" data-target="#collapsePoles" data-toggle="collapse" title="Poles">
    <img _ngcontent-c11="" class="mlr10" src="./assets/images/lamp-pole-group-12x12.png"> Poles
    <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fr mlr10 w15">
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-minus caret1 plr5"></span>
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-plus caret1 plr5"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <!----><ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="collapse" id="collapsePoles">
    <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel pr15" routerlinkactive="active" title="Poles Management" tabindex="0">Poles
      Management</li>
    <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pr15 pl1cm overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Poles Association with Hierarchy" tabindex="0">Poles
      Association with Hierarchy</li>

  </ul>
  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="arrow-toggle collapsed" data-target="#collapseLamps" data-toggle="collapse" title="Lamps">
    <img _ngcontent-c11="" class="mlr10" src="./assets/images/pole-lamps-12x12.png"> Lamps
    <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fr mlr10 w15">
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-minus caret1 plr5"></span>
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-plus caret1 plr5"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <!----><ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="collapse" id="collapseLamps">

    <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel pr15" routerlinkactive="active" title="Lamp Management" tabindex="0">Lamp
      Management</li>
    <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel pr15" routerlinkactive="active" title="Lamp Association with Poles" tabindex="0">Lamp
      Association with Poles</li>
  </ul>
  <!---->
  <!---->

  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="li-h" style="display: inherit;">Group
    Actions</li>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="arrow-toggle collapsed overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Commissioning Process" type="button" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:lightblue">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class=" mlr10 w15" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img _ngcontent-c11="" src="./assets/images/Commissioning-Process.png" class="mCS_img_loaded">
      </div>
    </i>Commissioning Process

  </li>

  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="arrow-toggle collapsed" data-target="#collapseGroup2" data-toggle="collapse" title="TCL-Multicast" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#97972d;">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-rss mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>TCL-Multicast
    <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fr mlr10">
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-minus caret1 plr5"></span>
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-plus caret1 plr5"></span>
    </span>
  </li>

  <ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="collapse " id="collapseGroup2">
    <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" title="Configuration" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">Configuration</li>
    <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" routerlinkactive="active" title="Broadcasting" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">Broadcasting</li>
  </ul>
  <!---->
  <ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="collapse " id="collapseGroup1">
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </ul>

  <!---->
  <ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="collapse " id="collapseGroup3">
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </ul>

  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="li-h" style="display: inherit;">Reports</li>
  <!----><li _ngcontent-c11="" class="arrow-toggle collapsed" data-target="#collapseReports" data-toggle="collapse" title="Reports" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#d3d347;">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-bar-chart mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Custom Reports
    <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fr mlr10">
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-minus caret1 plr5"></span>
      <span _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-plus caret1 plr5"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <!----><ul _ngcontent-c11="" class="collapse " id="collapseReports">
    <!---->
    <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Health Report" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">

      Health Report</li>
    <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="pl1cm overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Reports" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">Reports</li>
  </ul>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" class=" overflowEllipsel" routerlinkactive="active" title="Email Scheduler" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;"><i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#a2a284;">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-envelope mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Email Scheduler</l
    <li _ngcontent-c11="" class="li-h" style="display: inherit;">Other</li>
  <li _ngcontent-c11="" routerlinkactive="active" title="Archival" tabindex="0" style="display: inherit;">
    <i _ngcontent-c11="" aria-hidden="true">
      <div _ngcontent-c11="" class="fa fa-archive mlr10 aligncenter"></div>
    </i>Archival</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Update the question with error message.

Comment: you can try this :- driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("design-series")).click();

Answer (score 0):

in this you need to find partial link of element

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("design-series")).click();
```

If above code:-

```
WebElement hover = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-11496\"]"));        
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", hover);
```

**JavaScriptExecutor** is an Interface that helps to execute JavaScript through Selenium Webdriver.In Selenium Webdriver, locators like XPath, CSS, etc. are used to identify and perform operations on a web page.

In case, these locators do not work you can use JavaScriptExecutor. You can use JavaScriptExecutor to perform an desired operation on a web element.

**JavaScriptExecutor Methods**

1)executeAsyncScript

With Asynchronous script, your page renders more quickly. Instead of forcing users to wait for a script to download before the page renders. This function will execute an asynchronous piece of JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window in Selenium. The JS so executed is single-threaded with a various callback function which runs synchronously.

2)executeScript

This method executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window in Selenium. The script used in this method runs in the body of an anonymous function (a function without a name). We can also pass complicated arguments to it.

The script can return values. Data types returned are

-Boolean

-Long

-String

-List

-WebElement

The basic syntax for JavascriptExecutor is given below:

Syntax:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript(Script,Arguments);
```

Script – This is the JavaScript that needs to execute.

Arguments – It is the arguments to the script. It's optional.

need more information then go through this [link](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/javascript-and-selenium-javascriptexecutor/)